# Nesting in experimental desing

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-data

Suppose I have following results from my 2 experiments that contain 3 Block each and there are 4 treatments per Block (the example is `R` based)

```
dft <- data.frame(Exp = rep(1:2, each = 12), 
                 Block = rep(rep(1:3, each = 4), each = 2), 
                 Treat = rep(1:4, 6), 
                 Plot = rep(1:12, 2),
                 y = rnorm(24, mean = 10, sd = 2))
```

I want to find out if there are differences between `Treat` and `Exp`.
I used folowing model

```
library(nlme)
myMod <- lme(y ~ Exp*Treat, random = ~1|Block/Plot, data = dft, method = "ML")
```

but I got the comment that I should include `Block` nested in `Exp` in my model I did that too

```
myMod1 <- lme(y ~ Exp/Block + Exp*Treat, random = ~1|Block/Plot, data = dft, method = "ML")
```

and than compare both models which were not significantly different

```
anova(myMod, myMod1)
```

if there are no differences which model is more logical in this case???

Comment: The simplest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The principle of Occam's Razor, or model parsimony, would apply here. Given two models with similar results, we should prefer the simpler one.